# When we have 3 node with 2 data centers, how we can down 1 of dc completely and can use it? during Disaster recovery

Tags: cockroachdb, disaster-recovery

We have a 3 node by 3 node in 2 data centers (6 nodes). And as per example scenarios mentioned in Cockroachdb portal we can only down 2 nodes and must be 4 nodes available. However in our case, we want to down 3 nodes from a data center completely and still want to access another data center without issues and should be resolved when both data centers available.

I need suggestions/advice, how we can achieve this Disaster Recovery scenario, where assumed one of the Data center fully not reachable?

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, with 2 zones the cluster is unable to survive the loss of a single zone. See https://www.cockroachlabs.com/docs/stable/topology-patterns.html#anti-patterns

You'd need to deploy in 3 regions if you want to survive the loss of one whole region.